# making best quality images for iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode, image

Can someone tell me which iOS devices use which image sizes (1x,2x,3x)? and when creating an image would it be best to make it small and upscale it or make it bigger and downscale it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are supporting iOS8+ iPhones 1x images are not required any more, but still required only for iPad2.
For scalable images, i think that you should use bigger image and downscale it.

Comment: Why do you say they are not required then say they are required?

Comment: Yes not required for iOS8+ **iPhone** projects (Because all iOS8+ iPhones has a retina display). But if you are working on iOS8+ **iPad** projects, 1x images still required, because iPad2 still supporting iOS8 and it doesn't have a retina display.

Comment: But all iPhone apps run on iPads therefore all iPhone-only apps can be run on an iPad 2.

Comment: Right, but im currently testing an iPhone-only app on an iOS8 iPad 2 and i show that 2x images are being used (because i don't have 1x images on my project)